# How to stop body scroll in IOS when modal open (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I found this guide which works:
https://codepen.io/geoffgraham/pen/LogERe

I've created this helper that uses the code in my react app:

```
 export const removeBodyScrollingWhenModalOpen = (
        modalOpen: boolean,
    ) => {
        if (modalOpen) {
            document.body.style.position = 'fixed';
            document.body.style.top = `-${window.scrollY}px`;
        } else {
            const scrollY = document.body.style.top;
            document.body.style.position = '';
            document.body.style.top = '';
            window.scrollTo(0, parseInt(scrollY || '0') * -1);
        }
 };
```

When used with the modal:

```
const handleClose = () => {
    onClose(false);
    removeBodyScrollingWhenModalOpen(false);
};

useEffect(() => {
    removeBodyScrollingWhenModalOpen(open);
}, [open]);
```

However, to make the code work properly and not loose scroll position when the modal is closed, I need to add this bit of code:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--scroll-y', `${window.scrollY}px`);
});
```

But not sure how to implement that with my hook above, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the best solution I came up with:

```
export const removeBodyScrollingWhenModalOpen = (modalOpen: boolean) => {
    console.log('modalOpen: ', modalOpen);
    const body = document.body;
    if (modalOpen && isMobile()) {
        const scrollY = document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue('--scroll-y');
        body.style.position = 'fixed';
        body.style.top = `-${scrollY}`;
    } else if (!modalOpen && isMobile()) {
        const scrollY = body.style.top;
        body.style.position = '';
        body.style.top = '';
        window.scrollTo(0, parseInt(scrollY || '0') * -1);
    } else if (modalOpen) {
        document.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
    } else {
        document.body.style.overflowY = 'visible';
    }
};
```